# Transcription d'une vidéo

Tags: oral

J'ai transcrit [cette vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrDXNV8FSzg) mais il m'en reste quelques lacunes. Pouvez-vous m'aider à les remplir ?

À 33 secondes : *il y a des ___ dans le ciel*

À 2 m 14 : *Mimi ___*

À 2 m 49 : *Je dois __ (majoritairement??) tous ces abonnés __ (comme?) vous, qui êtes très gentils, je vous aime bien. Et un (pe)tit mot à ___ (chacun?) qui a commenté ma vidéo*

Merci d'avance.

Comment: Cette question ne porte pas sur la langue française mais demande un service (vote pour clôture).

Comment: Merci beaucoup, et désolée. Je ne savais pas que ce genre de question n'était pas permis.

Comment: Pas de souci, l'erreur est humaine. Ce n'est que mon avis et il se peut que ce soit moi qui sois en tort. [La FAQ](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ne dit rien de particulier à cet égard, mais j'aurais tendance à rapprocher ça des demandes de traduction.

Comment: @Chop Je crois que c'est valide. Si ikl avait juste dit "Il y a des expressions que je ne saisi pas dans cette vidéo" sans mentionner la transcription, personne ne songerait à voter pour clore la question,

Comment: J'ai changé mon commentaire en réponse, afin que la question en ait une si elle reste ouverte.

Comment: @Chop Personnellement, je vois un gros effort de la part de l'OP, il ne demande pas toutes les phrases, il a essayé de retranscrire autant qu'il pouvait et il ne lui manque que quelques mot (dont 2 noms propres, difficiles pour les non natifs...). La question me semble donc valide, et ne demande pas beaucoup d'effort de notre part contrairement à une simple transcription / traduction d'un texte entier...

Comment: @Random Je suis d'accord, c'est pour ça que j'ai tenu à aider en premier lieu. Le problème est alors (comme toujours) de réussir à tracer une ligne entre ce qui est acceptable et ce qui ne l'est pas. Pourquoi acceptons-nous une question de ce type aujourd'hui et la refuserons-nous à l'avenir ? La remarque de Circeus sur le fait qu'il s'agit d'une demande d'aide à la compréhension plutôt que la transcription est également tout à fait valable.

Comment: @Chop Je pense que la limite est la réponse à la question "est-ce j'ai envie de l'aider ?". Car personnellement, j'aime répondre à des questions quand l'OP est intéressé, quand il a essayé de comprendre. Je vais passer 15 minutes pour que l'OP gagne 4h, c'est rentable (15min vs 4h) et agréable (j'ai rendu service à quelqu'un qui a travaillé), donc si je trouve ça "offtopic" (Un "do my homework", ou "let me google it for you"), je n'ai pas envie de perdre mon temps. Si une personne répond, elle fait ce qu'elle veut de son temps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

33 s

> Il y a des avions dans le ciel.

---

2 m 14 s

> Mimie Mathy *style's*

(avec un génitif saxon mal placé, à la *French style*)

---

2 m 49 s

> Je dois majoritairement tous ces abonnés — dont vous, qui êtes très gentil ; je vous aime bien — à Timothée Hochet<sup>1</sup>, qui a commenté ma vidéo, ...

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Timothée Hochet est un casteur Youtube. Merci à [Random](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7321/random) pour sa recherche et la correction apportée à la dernière transcription.</sub>

Comment: Concernant la dernière phrase, je n'entend pas le premier **le** et "à", je pense que la phrase simplifiée est "je dois tous ces abonnés à Timothée Hochet", car en le cherchant sur google, c'est un caster youtube, et il a du lui amener du trafic. La phrase serait donc "Je dois majoritairement tous ces abonnés -dont vous, qui êtes très gentil. Je vous aime bien- à Timothée Hochet1, qui a gentiment commenté ma vidéo, ..."

Comment: @Random Ça explique la phrase qui était bancale. Merci !

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! C'est beaucoup plus logique. Voici ce que j'ai fait avec : https://www.lawlessfrench.com/listening/10-cliches-francais/

Comment: @lkl Je note une légère erreur dans le cliché 8, le mot aspiré est "**ils**", et non "**ne**", la phrase est "les gars de la côte ouest des États-Unis **ils** font plus ça". Le reste est impeccable :)

Comment: Merci beaucoup, j'apprécie énormément votre assistance.  :-)

Comment: Phrase qui ne veut absolument rien dire donc... j'ai presque envie de dire: à quoi bon la retranscrire ?

Comment: @MrUpsidown qu'est-ce qui ne veut rien dire ?

Comment: Pardon, je parlais de la phrase à 2'49. Mais je viens tout juste d'en comprendre le sens en la relisant (avec la syntaxe correcte dans la réponse de Chop). Donc ne tenez pas compte de mon commentaire, merci.